# How to get svn directory status using pysvn

Tags: python, svn, pysvn

I try to get directory "svn" status (unversionned, normal, ...) of a particular directory using pysvn Client.status(dirname) function.

But as said in the doc, pysvn return an array with file status within directory, not directory himself.

Is there an other way to obtain this information ?

Have a nice day.
Ouille

Answer (score 1):

Sorry found it.

Client.status(dirname) return an array. Last element of this array is the directory.

So using `myclient.status(dirname)[-1].text_status` return directory status.

Have a nice day.
Ouille.